# mySQL: Get 3 month interval from previous interval

Tags: mysql, sql

```
select pd.state AS StateName, pd.county AS `County Name`,
   SUM(pc.close_dt >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 3 MONTH) AS `0-3 Months`, 
   SUM(`0-3 Months` - INTERVAL 3 MONTH) AS `3-6 Months`


from resnet.property_details pd join
 resnet.property_closings pc
 on pd.property_id = pc.Property_id
group by pd.state, pd.county;
```

How can I get the 3 month interval from the previous 3 month interval value? So it will be 3-6 months?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `BETWEEN..AND`, e.g.:

```
select pd.state AS StateName, pd.county AS `County Name`,
   SUM(pc.close_dt >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 3 MONTH) AS `0-3 Months`, 
   SUM(pc.close_dt BETWEEN CURDATE() - INTERVAL 3 MONTH AND CURDATE() - INTERVAL 6 MONTH) AS `3-6 Months`
from resnet.property_details pd join
 resnet.property_closings pc
 on pd.property_id = pc.Property_id
group by pd.state, pd.county;
```